# Difference between "現住所" and "連絡先" on Japanese resume?

Tags: word-choice

"現住所" and "連絡先" are 2 fields on a Japanese resume. If both are the same address, do you:

- delete the "現住所" and just list the "連絡先"?
- delete the "連絡先" field and just list your "現住所"?

Or, are there any other options?

Comment: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q136943328

Answer (score 5, accepted):

現住所 is the place where you live, i.e. your home address.
連絡先 is the point (in most cases phone number) that the recipient of your resume can take contact with somebody responsible in case you are not available on the phone number of your home address.
When I make a trip abroad, the travel agency requests me to fill in my 現住所 and 連絡先 in the designated application form, and I put down my own home address and phone number in 現住所 box, and phone number (and address if required) of my eldest daughter who lives nearby my house in 連絡先 box, in case the travel agency needs to take an emergency contact with my family when they need to do so during my absence.

In short, 連絡先 is the contact point (phone number) that the recipient of your resume can connect you or your proxy as a backup to your own phone number.